# Quiero hacer una consulta mediante WHERE id_usuarios = 53

Tags: mysql

Mi código:

```
SELECT numero_empleado, nombre, paterno, materno, fec_nac, estado, genero, edociv, hijos, 
id_contact FROM grl_usuarios 
INNER JOIN grl_usuarios_contacto
ON grl_usuarios.id_usuario = grl_usuarios_contacto.id_usuario 
WHERE id_usuario = 53
```

> **ERROR:**  column reference "id_usuario" is ambiguous
>   LINE 3: ..._usuario = grl_usuarios_contacto.id_usuario where id_usuario.
>
> **ERROR:** column reference "id_usuario" is ambiguous
>   SQL state: 42702
>   Character: 231

Comment: deberías poner mas información acerca de la tablas como por ejemplo las columnas que tienen.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Answer (score 3):

Deberías agregar un alias a cada tabla ya que tenes 2 campos con el mismo nombre (En este caso Id_usuarios)de esta forma te evitas la ambigüedad de la columnas.

A cada columna le deberas agregar un alias en este caso de ejemplo que te puse (a o b) según corresponda.

```
      select 
             a.numero_empleado
             , a.nombre
             , a.paterno
             , b.materno
             , b.fec_nac
             , b.estado
             , b.genero
             , a.edociv
             , b.hijos
             , a.id_contact 
        from grl_usuarios a
            inner join grl_usuarios_contacto b
                 on grl_usuarios.id_usuario = grl_usuarios_contacto.id_usuario 
where a.id_usuario = 53
```

Comment: pero esto igual daría error. Hay que cambiar el WHERE para decir `WHERE a.id_usuario=53`

Comment: Si tenes razon ahi modifique la consulta!

Answer (score 3):

Estimado, ese error le aparece porque las dos tablas tienen una columna que se llama id_usuario, cuando coloca where id_usuario = 53, el motor de base de datos no sabe si es de la tabla grl_usuarios o de la tabla grl_usuarios_contacto. Para solucionar este problema, le suguiero colocar un alias a la tabla. Le dejo una consulta a modo de suguerencia. Saludos.

```
SELECT usr.numero_empleado, usr.nombre, usr.paterno, usr.materno, usr.fec_nac, usr.estado, usr.genero, usr.edociv, usr.hijos, 
usrCon.id_contact FROM grl_usuarios usr 
INNER JOIN grl_usuarios_contacto usrCon
ON usr.id_usuario = usrCon.id_usuario 
WHERE usr.id_usuario = 53
```

O bien como la tiene solmante agregando una palabra más a su sentencia:

```
SELECT numero_empleado, nombre, paterno, materno, fec_nac, estado, genero, edociv, hijos, 
 id_contact FROM grl_usuarios 
INNER JOIN grl_usuarios_contacto
ON grl_usuarios.id_usuario = grl_usuarios_contacto.id_usuario 
WHERE grl_usuarios.id_usuario = 53
```